# isDisabled property in ngx-bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

I have implemented the tooltip of ngx-bootstrap and the tooltip is working fine in the normal scenario. But I want to display the tooltip on conditional basis.

When I include isDisabled property, I do not see the tooltip on any of the below scenario. Am I missing something?

```
<span tooltip="{{toolTipText}}" triggers="" #pop="bs-tooltip" placement="bottom" isDisabled="true"></span>
<button type="button" (click)="toggleSelect()" (mouseenter)="pop.show()" (mouseleave)="pop.hide()">
    <span class="pull-left">Click Here!</span>
</button>
```

(or)

```
<span tooltip="{{toolTipText}}" triggers="" #pop="bs-tooltip" placement="bottom" isDisabled="false"></span>
<button type="button" (click)="toggleSelect()" (mouseenter)="pop.show()" (mouseleave)="pop.hide()">
    <span class="pull-left">Click Here!</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `[bracket syntax]` to evaluate input parameters as javascript instead of static values.

Meaning you need to do `[isDisabled]="false/true"`instead of `isDisabled="false/true"`. Doing the later example will actually pass in the string 'true' or 'false'

Here is a working [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bOGfCvzSvn6jd1vvAkn9?p=preview)

```
<div style="margin: 100px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary"
    tooltip="isDisable = true"
    [isDisabled]="true"
    placement="top">
    isDisable = true
  </button>
</div>
<div style="margin: 100px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary"
    tooltip="isDisable = false"
    [isDisabled]="false"
    placement="top">
    isDisable = false
  </button>
</div>
```